How can I disconnect Bluetooth headphones so that it stays disconnected until I reconnect it myself?
When I disconnect Bluetooth headphones, it automatically reconnect after a while (about 1 day? I don't know exactly). How can I disconnect Bluetooth headphones so that it stays disconnected until I reconnect it myself? I use Windows 10 Pro 21H2. I don't want to forget it though as I don't want to have to pair it again.

